# How to dynamically select elements with document.querySelectorAll() for function call?

Tags: javascript

I have been working on this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/j1vrb7to/165/

The code in that fiddle is this:

HTML:

```
<div id="CalculationContainer">
  <input type="numbers" class="form-control new-tuition" /> <br />
  <input type="numbers" class="form-control new-tuition" /> <br />
  <input type="numbers" class="form-control new-tuition" /><br /><br />
  <input type="numbers" id="new-tuition-total" disabled="disabled" /><br /> <br />

  <input type="numbers" class="form-control new-state" /> <br />
  <input type="numbers" class="form-control new-state" /> <br />
  <input type="numbers" class="form-control new-state" /><br /><br />
  <input type="numbers" id="new-state-total" disabled="disabled" />
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
const NewTuitionInputs = document.querySelectorAll("div#CalculationContainer > input.new-tuition");
const NewStateInputs = document.querySelectorAll("div#CalculationContainer > input.new-state");

NewTuitionInputs.forEach(function(input) {
  input.onchange = function() {
    var total = 0;
    NewTuitionInputs.forEach(function(input) {
      total += parseInt(input.value);
    });
    document.getElementById("new-tuition-total").value = total;
  }
});

NewStateInputs.forEach(function(input) {
  input.onchange = function() {
    var total = 0;
    NewStateInputs.forEach(function(input) {
      total += parseInt(input.value);
    });
    document.getElementById("new-state-total").value = total;
  }
});
```

As the users enter values into the textboxes, I want to update the value of another field to display running totals. Ultimately I will need to keep track of 20+ running totals on my form. Instead of maintaining 20+ functions, is it possible to use a single function to calculate running totals on the fly? Here is some pseudocode to demonstrate what I'm thinking:

```
var ThisInput = document.querySelectorAll("div#CalculationContainer > input.[INPUT_CLASS_PARAMETER_HERE]");

ThisInput.forEach(function(input) {
  input.onchange = function() {
    var total = 0;
    ThisInput.forEach(function(input) {
      total += parseInt(input.value);
    });
    document.getElementById("[DYNAMICALLY_CHOOSE_WHERE_TO_DISPLAY").value = total;
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes. It's possible. Grab all input elements that have the same class as the one that got changed, and store the result in the element with the id `<class>` + `-total`. Or wrap the elements that belong to each other in an element + `this` and some DOM traversal.

Comment: Yes it's possible. Main question is, are you stuck with you current markup, or are you free to make changes to the HTML elements? When creating your form, what you could do, is have an outer container for each section instead of having everything clumped up in one big container. This way you could iterate through each container and their input fields and make your calculations.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid : `input type="numbers"`  doesn't exist in HTML use `input type="number"`

Comment: @MisterJojo Ha, good find. Funnily enough, I made that mistake in my fiddle but not in my application. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a convention that the inputs have a class and then the total has an id with that class name plus `-total`. You can use this to your advantage in making a general purpose function:

```
function trackTotals(className){
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll(`div#CalculationContainer > input.${className}`);
    inputs.forEach(input => {
      input.addEventListener("change",()=>{
        var total = [...inputs].reduce((acc,i) => acc + (parseInt(i.value,10) || 0),0);
        document.getElementById(`${className}-total`).value = total;
      })
    })
}
```

Usage would then be:

```
trackTotals("new-tuition");
trackTotals("new-state");
// whatever else that follows same conventions
```

Live example follows:

```js
trackTotals("new-tuition");
trackTotals("new-state");

function trackTotals(className){
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll(`div#CalculationContainer > input.${className}`);
  inputs.forEach(input => {
    input.addEventListener("change",()=>{
      var total = [...inputs].reduce((acc,i) => acc + (parseInt(i.value,10) || 0),0);
      document.getElementById(`${className}-total`).value = total;
    })
  })
}
```

```html
<div id="CalculationContainer">
<input type="numbers" class="form-control new-tuition"/> <br/>
<input type="numbers" class="form-control new-tuition"/> <br/>
<input type="numbers" class="form-control new-tuition"/><br/><br/>
<input type="numbers" id="new-tuition-total" disabled="disabled"/><br /><br />

<input type="numbers" class="form-control new-state"/> <br/>
<input type="numbers" class="form-control new-state"/> <br/>
<input type="numbers" class="form-control new-state"/><br/><br/>
<input type="numbers" id="new-state-total" disabled="disabled"/>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a function that takes the id:

```
function doTotal(name) {
    var ThisInput = document.querySelectorAll(`div#CalculationContainer > input.${name}`);
    
    ThisInput.forEach(function(input) {
        input.onchange = function() {
            var total = 0;
            ThisInput.forEach(function(input) {
                total += parseInt(input.value);
            });
            document.getElementById(`${name}-total`).value = total;
        }
    });
}
```

Note that I'm using string templates to build the selector strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the event delegation method:

```js
const calcContainer = document.getElementById('CalculationContainer')
    , sumElms = 
      { tuition: { sum: document.getElementById('new-tuition-total'), elms: [...document.querySelectorAll('input.new-tuition')] } 
      , state:   { sum: document.getElementById('new-state-total'),   elms: [...document.querySelectorAll('input.new-state')]   }
      }
    ;
calcContainer.oninput= ({target}) => 
  {
  if (!target.matches('.new-tuition, .new-state')) return
  let sumElm = target.matches('.new-tuition') ? sumElms.tuition : sumElms.state
  sumElm.sum.value = sumElm.elms.reduce((s,e)=>s+e.valueAsNumber,0)
  }
```

```css
#CalculationContainer input {
  float: left;
  clear:both;
  width: 5em;
}
#CalculationContainer input:disabled {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color:black;
}
```

```html
<div id="CalculationContainer">
  <input type="number" class="form-control new-tuition" value="0"> 
  <input type="number" class="form-control new-tuition" value="0"> 
  <input type="number" class="form-control new-tuition" value="0">
  <input type="number" id="new-tuition-total" disabled="disabled" value="0">
  
  <input type="number" class="form-control new-state" value="0"> 
  <input type="number" class="form-control new-state"value="0"> 
  <input type="number" class="form-control new-state"value="0">
  <input type="number" id="new-state-total" disabled="disabled"value="0">
</div>
```